# How to use annotation to replace mvc:resources namespace

Tags: xml, spring, resources, annotations, spring-webflow

I am building a project using annotation to do the configuration job.

And when I doing this, I cannot find a way to use annotation to replace mvc:resources namespace tag.

I can provide an example about what I want.

Example: use annotation to replace `<mvc:annotation-driven />`.

```
@Configuration
@Lazy(false)
public class MVCContainerConfig 
{   
    /**
     * Define (MVC) Annotation Method Handler Adapter. (Same as <mvc:annotation-driven /> in XML)
     */
    @Bean
    public AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter annotationMethodHandlerAdapter()
    {
        ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer configurableWebBindingInitializer = new ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer();
        configurableWebBindingInitializer.setValidator(localValidatorFactoryBean());

        AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter annotationMethodHandlerAdapter = new AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter();
        annotationMethodHandlerAdapter.setWebBindingInitializer(configurableWebBindingInitializer);
        annotationMethodHandlerAdapter.setMessageConverters(new HttpMessageConverter[]{
            new BufferedImageHttpMessageConverter(), 
            new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter(),
            new FormHttpMessageConverter(), 
            new ResourceHttpMessageConverter(), 
            new StringHttpMessageConverter(),
            new AtomFeedHttpMessageConverter(),
            new RssChannelHttpMessageConverter(),
            new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter(),
            new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter(), 
            new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter(),
            new XmlAwareFormHttpMessageConverter()
        });

        return annotationMethodHandlerAdapter;
    }

    ... ...
}
```

So based on the above example, is there a way to use annotation to replace `<mvc:resources />` namespace tag?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `@EnableWebMvc`. But this is a Spring 3.1 Feature!

@see this Blog: [Spring 3.1 M2: Spring MVC Enhancements](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/06/13/spring-3-1-m2-spring-mvc-enhancements-2/)